# Member field aliases in derived class (no accessor functions)

Tags: c++, c++17

Toy example:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
public:
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return m_elements[i]; }
    T const& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return m_elements[i]; }

private:
    std::array<T, N> m_elements;
};

template<typename T>
class vector3
    : public static_vector<T, 3>
{
public:
    using vector_type = static_vector<T, 3>;

//  x = vector_type::operator[](0);
//  y = vector_type::operator[](1);
//  z = vector_type::operator[](2);
};
```

Let `vector3<float> pos;`. I want to access `pos[0]` via `pos.x`. Clearly, if `pos` is declared to be `const`, I want `pos.x` to be read-only.

Is this possible?

Let me stress the fact that I don't want to use accessor functions of the form

```
T& x() { return (*this)[0]; }
T const& x() const { return (*this)[0]; }
```

Comment: You might add references... but then `vector3` would be bigger, and you would have to write copy constructor.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind except for what you have already.  May I ask why you don't want to use what you have?  It should be optimized away.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm just interested whether there are any other options.

Comment: If you want to access the same data with different names you'd have to use a `union`. It's more of a C way of doing things though. It's worth checking out the GLM mathematics library. I believe they use this trick for their vector classes to allow access via x, y, z or r, g, b. They don't however use it for array access. To do a vec3 with an array and xyz members you'd have to use compiler specific commands to enable 1 byte packing. You really don't want to start down that type punning rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

There is no zero cost way to do this using the exact syntax you want.

Relaxing either cost (compile, maintenance, memory usage and runtime) or syntax (which your `()` is an example of) gets you what you want.

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly the sort of thing member functions are _for_.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to your question but I thought I'd add an answer with some code to clarify. Be warned, what follows is *not a good idea*.

You can use simple pointer arithmetic to interpret members of a `struct` as if they were elements in an `array`. Because the type of the `struct` members and the type of elements in the pseudo `array` are the same, we're safe to reinterpret one as the other **with the caveat** that there is no padding in between the `struct` members.

The C++ standard gives no method for defining padding in a `struct` so you will have to rely on compiler specific directives. I believe however that both MSVC and GCC support `#pragma pack`.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T>
struct Vec3
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;

    T& operator[](size_t i) { return *(&x + i); }
    const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return *(&x + i); }
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

So why isn't this a good solution?

- You are relying on compiler specific directives making your code less portable.
- You need to explicitly declare each member which means you'll need separate templates for Vec2, Vec3 and Vec4.
- 1 byte alignment isn't supported on all architectures again making your code less portable.
- Even on architectures where unaligned memory access is supported (such as x86,) it comes with a performance penalty.